# Get HTML source code as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the source code of an HTML page (`1.html`) to be used in another page (`2.html`). Furthermore, I want to perform operations on it in `2.html`.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: `1.html` is a separate public webpage and I do not have access to make changes to its source code. I have to do whatever I need only by using `2.html`.

Comment: What kind of operations?

Comment: Do you want to get the whole content of 1.html page from 2.html using jQuery? You could make an AJAX request and get it if I understood right what you want to do.

Comment: @Pekka: Simple operations like extracting some innerHTML from 1.html and displaying it into 2.html Aldo 'xeon': its a cross domain request, so AJAX does not work.

Answer (score 22):

To get the DOM converted to a string:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

Question: what do you mean by "use it"? Do you need to include 1.html inside 2.html? Or do you just need to process it?

Comment: Poster wants a different pages HTML.

Comment: i just need to process it.. I have access to change the source code of only 2.html..

Comment: `.innerHTML` doesn't actually return the source code, it generates html to correspond to the current DOM tree. Subtle difference, but still...

Comment: a source code is the unprocessed html that the website developer wrote.  `innerHTML` would give the DOM converted into a string. A DOMed html would have been fixed for html errors (with varying degree) and javascript changes would be refledted in it.

Comment: reflected. Also, check the OP's comment to his own post: he needs elements from that page to display them again somewhere else. The correct DOM here suits him best. Asking for the "source code" of a page isn't really feasible unless you have direct access to the original, unprocessed, unfiltered by the server, file. I hope he's fine now, 2 years after.

Comment: browser* @SamueleMattiuzzo

Comment: Urgh, I can't edit it anymore, but thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple

On `2.html` use this jQuery snippet

```
$.get("1.html", function(response) { 
    alert(response) 
    //do you operations
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand whatyou mean that you must make modifications, but you could simply load the second page through AJAX

```
var url ="1.html";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'html'
  success: function(data){
             //do something with data, which is the page 1.html
           }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use can use .html method alternatively to get the entire html data of the page.

```
$(function(){
    var a = ($('html').html())
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

A realy simple and modern way is the follow:

```
fetch('1.html').then(function(response) {
    /* when the page is loaded convert it to plain text */
    return response.text()
}).then(function(html) {
    /* initialize the DOM parser */
    var initParser = new DOMParser();
    /* parse the text */
    var parse = initParser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    /* you can now even select part of that html as you would in the regular DOM */ 
    /* example */
    var docOutput = parse.querySelector('html').outerHTML;
    console.log(docOutput);
}).catch(function(error) {  
    console.log('Error fetch page: ', error);  
});
```